# App layer 3d showcase tutorial

Tags: photoshop

I have found a bunch of images showcasing an app in a very nice way.
Can anyone link to a good tutorial on how to do these in Photoshop:

[image: Showcase 1]

[image: Showcase 2]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Here's some good mockups.
http://designbeep.com/2013/10/04/15-free-perspective-screen-mockups-showcase-app-design/